# What happens when I "save" in Xcode IDE

Tags: xcode, xcode8, autosave

I'm just starting to learn Swift using the Apple Xcode IDE.  I made a little test iOS app and was trying various things when I inadvertently deleted my main code file (ViewController.swift). "No problem", I thought, as I had hit "Save" just a couple of minutes before. I exited out, then came back in, but it appeared to have autosaved.

I don't really care about this test file, but am wondering what is the proper way to save a project before trying something out (or before inadvertently pulling a bonehead move)?

Comment: I would look into `git` source control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git). If you don't know what it is, look into it. In the mean time, here is a [tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials) or [two](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1).

To use it in Xcode, when you create a project, be sure to create a git repo:

[image]

Then be sure to commit frequently. Xcode has a built in Git GUI, so that makes it easier:

[image]

Then if you do anything that you shouldn't have you can either discard all changes (see the above screen shot, or if that can't help you, you can:

1. Open the 'Terminal' app
2. `cd` to the directory with the project
3. Run `git log`
4. Find the commit before you ruined everything
5. Copy the commit hash
6. Type `q` to exit the log
7. Run `git reset --hard <THE-HASH-YOU-COPIED>`

That should do it for you.

Comment: So there is no way to disable autosave in XCode? What is the Save button for then?

Comment: @cakan What do you mean by autosaving? The save button is to update the files on disk, it doesn't commit on the git repo.

Comment: I just want to use XCode (without git) to read or edit some file . As soon as I type anything in that file, it gets automatically saved to the disk. It looks like you don't need to use Save button at all. Anyway, I've found a way to disable autosave via terminal with the following command `defaults write $(osascript -e 'id of application "Xcode"') ApplePersistence -bool False`

Answer (score 2):

**What happens when I “save” in Xcode IDE?**

When you hit "Save" the changes you've made are saved to disk. XCode doesn't do this automatically. If it crashes you may lose all your code written after the last time it was saved to disk. But XCode saves the changes to disk even without hitting "Save" button in some cases.

> Xcode automatically saves changes to source, project, and workspace
> files as you work. This feature requires no configuration, because
> Xcode continuously tracks your changes and saves them in memory. Xcode
> then writes these changes to disk whenever you:
>
> Build and run your app
>
> Commit files to a source code repository
>
> Close the project
>
> Quit Xcode

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/UsingFileSaving.html

Answer (score -1):

When creating a project check 'create git repository on my mac'.

Then commit changes when you're finished with one minor part and give the commit a comment so you know when looking into the history what changes you have done (quick overview).

With git you can quickly revert changes and go back to certain revisions like you can do in TimeMachine.

Further information are available at [git's webpage](https://git-scm.com/about).